# How to add a variable to exists text?

Tags: php, laravel

I have simple update method in laravel:

```
$withdraw->update([
    'trade_id' => $data['trade_id']
]);
```

And i received numbers `1111111`.

I need add `$data['trade_id']` to link `https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/` and get `https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/1111111`

I try to make:

```
$withdraw->update([
    'trade_id' => 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/'.$data['trade_id']
]);
```

But it doesn't work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Does trade_id accept string? Probably not. If so, this is your problem. You can create a new column to store links, or you can generate links on the fly when you fetch data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems trade_id has int data type, change trade_id data type (if its not a primary key or foreign key) to varchar